# Ionic 2 Google Plus Authetication

Tags: ionic2

google login authentication in ionic 2 
with step by step.
 i try to print simple response but it does not work

```
GLogin(){   
     alert("you are in google plush "); 
     GooglePlus.login((res)=>{       
         alert(this.data=res);   
     });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the plugin (check this [link](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus)):

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus --save --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=myreversedclientid
```

Include the lib:

```
import { GooglePlus } from 'ionic-native';
```

Now the **login**:

```
googlePlus_login() {
    GooglePlus.login(
        {
            'scopes': '',
            'webClientId': '',
            'offline': false
        }
    ).then(
        (success) => {
            alert(  '\n id: ' + JSON.stringify(success.userId) +
                    '\n name: ' + JSON.stringify(success.displayName) +
                    '\n email: ' + JSON.stringify(success.email)
            );
        },
        (failure) => {
            console.log('GOOGLE+ login FAILED', failure);
        }
    );
}
```

where:

> scope: optional, space-separated list of scopes, If not included or empty, defaults to profile and email.
>
> webClientId: optional clientId of your Web application from Credentials settings of your project - On Android, this MUST be included to get an idToken. On iOS, it is not required.
>
> offline: optional, but requires the webClientId - if set to true the plugin will also return a serverAuthCode, which can be used to grant offline access to a non-Google server.

**Logout** function:

```
googlePlus_logout() {
    GooglePlus.logout().then(
        (success) => {
            console.log('GOOGLE+: logout DONE', success);
        },
        (failure) => {
            console.log('GOOGLE+: logout FAILED', failure);
        }
    );
}
```

Hope it will help you. :)